# Alternatives to anonymous class

Tags: object-oriented, language-design, language-features

In the language I work with, Progress OpenEdge 11.5.1, there is nothing like anonymous classes. However, the system design would really benefit the use of such classes.

Is there some nice known way of constructing such classes without having them in the language specification?

My thoughts goes like a class having a constructor that must be injected by the user object in a smart sense or a constructor with some key.

All ideas are welcome.

---

*Background:*

I have class A with one purpose: to calculate a value P.

Some users of A, but not all, need a heavy machinery in order to calculate P. 
Hence, I would like to hide such calculations for other users in order to speed up loading of the object A.

---

Comment: The primary point of anonymous classes is that they are generated and tracked by compiler. If you have programmer make the it, it becomes normal class.

Comment: What is the benefit you're looking for? Do you need a lot of classes having only one instance? Or is it more like you need a lot of implementations for some interfaces?

Comment: @COMEFROM The class A have one purpose, to calculate a value P. Some users, but not all, need a heavy machinery in order to calculate P. Hence, I would like to hide such calculations for other users in order to speed up loading of the object A.

Comment: So you need different implementations for different clients and you want to avoid consuming resources (CPU time, clock time, memory) when handling a case where "heavy machinery" is not needed, am I right? I think you should edit the question to make clear that's your goal. You're trying to solve a real problem after all, not just trying to mimic a language feature you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) to implement the various strategies to calculate P.

The basic idea is that you make a class for each version of the algorithms to calculate P, they each inherit from the same interface (for instance `ICalculateP`). Your `class A` would then have a member of type `ICalculateP` that binds on runtime to one of the concrete classes.

That way at runtime you can decide which strategy fits best with the specific situation.

Comment: Thanks, what I would like is that the strategy used should be coupled to the class A somehow, otherwise this is sort of what I would like.

Comment: Applying the strategy pattern would result in `class A` and the strategy being coupled (on runtime). You could choose to couple it with the lighter strategy by default and under certain circumstances couple it with the heavier version.